# How to avoid races if a signal is emitted before calling QObject::connect()?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qobject, qeventloop

In Qt, how does one avoid race conditions if signals can be emitted around the same time when I connect to them?

Consider the following naïve example:

```
MySignalSender *sender = new MySignalSender(); // starts async operation that emits `fooSignal`
// <-- Possibility (1): `fooSignal` can be emitted here
MySignalReceiver *receiver = new MySignalReceiver();
// <-- Possibility (2): `fooSignal` can be emitted here
QObject::connect(sender, &MySignalSender::fooSignal, receiver, &MySignalReceiver::fooSlot);
// <-- Possibility (3): `fooSignal` can be emitted here or later
```

Since `fooSignal` is emitted from another thread, the choice of possibilities 1-3 is realized non-deterministically by the scheduler at runtime. While the desired behavior would only be achieved in the third case, in the remaining two we lose the signal, likely leading to a deadlock or some other undefined behavior.

Does Qt offer some atomic mechanism to temporarily pause signals from objects? I'm aware of `QObject::blockSignals()`, however my understanding is that this suppresses signals *entirely* rather than just postponing them for a while.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to simply change the way you're constructing the objects sending the signals. You can separate the construction of the object from the starting of the async operation.

```
MySignalSender *sender = new MySignalSender();
MySignalReceiver *receiver = new MySignalReceiver();
QObject::connect(sender, &MySignalSender::fooSignal, receiver, &MySignalReceiver::fooSlot);

sender->startAsyncOperations();
```

Comment: Agreed, I would do this with objects that are within my control. Unfortunately this is not a possibility when calling Qt library objects, e.g. `QNetworkAccessManager::get()`. What to do then?

Comment: In that specific case, I've always connected to the QNetworkAccessManager, rather than the QNetworkReply. But I understand your point.

Comment: Oh that's cool, didn't know you could do that. Cheers!